# JPCAP Import Issues

Tags: java, netbeans, 64-bit, jpcap

I am using Windows 7 64bit. Currently, I have Netbeans 7.3 and jdk1.7.0_25 installed on my PC. I am trying to import JPCAP library to my project which I download from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpcap/.
But when I try to use the library : import jpcap.*; (there's red color underline on "jpcap") and the error message is : package jpcap does not exist. Unused Import.
Can anybody help me to figure this out.
Thank's a lot.

Comment: Have you set your classpath? Where did you put the JPCAP lib?

Comment: Yes, I do set the path and the environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

At first, JPCAP doesn't work on 64-bit platform(only 32-bit), and to use it you must download 32-bit jdk and 32-bit ide and install them on your pc.
Second, to include JPCAP you must do some stuff, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uump9bPIER8) will be so useful.

Comment: No, you don't have to setup 32-bit windows, all you have to do is to install 32-bit IDE and 32-bit JDK.

Comment: Well :), if it's helpful you can vote it up and if it's the desired answer you can accept it.